# Can this additional data improve the validity of Difference-in-Differences estimate

Tags: causality, difference-in-difference, research-design

I am aiming to measure the impact of a treatment (a marketing stimulus) on product revenue.
The data has resulted from a natural experiment. The set-up is tabulated below. Cells in the table indicate whether customers in a group received marketing stimulus or not.

| Customer group | Sales Quarter 1 | Sales Quarter 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Control group | No | No |
| Treatment Group 1 | No | Yes |

Because there is customer level data, I plan to estimate using a panel regression model with revenue in a quarter as Y and the following variables as Xs (I may include additional variables if the trends in TG & CG are different and unrelated to the treatment effects):

1. Dummy variable for whether customer revenue was measured in Quarter 1/ Quarter 2
2. Dummy variable for whether customer was in the treatment group/ control
3. The interaction between the two dummy variables, the co-efficient of which would be the **Difference-in-Differences estimate, or the estimate of the treatment effect.**

I stated the above to set context. My query however, is about an additional set of data that is available, indicated as treatment group 2 in the table below:

| Customer group | Sales Quarter 1 | Sales Quarter 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Control group | No | No |
| Treatment Group 1 | No | Yes |
| Treatment Group 2 | Yes | No |

My question is whether this information can be used to improve the validity of the study and if so, how?

Comment: hi,well if its study, give it chapter, describe input, collect/show results in graphs/tables. it can improve it. ..i mean, the reason to do research project is sometimes in process of documenting tests..in good way, many times good inventions are found in doing simple things ... many times including more data into X "increase" model accuracy, sometimes not .. my simple advice is to test it and see how things work :-) and document it

Comment: (1) Do you observe the same individuals over time? (2) Does the marketing stimulus start at the same time for all individuals in your treatment group(s)? (3) Might there be any overlap or synergy *between* the two treatment groups?

Comment: @ThomasBilach (1) Same individuals over time?  Yes, The individuals in a group e.g., TG1 remain the same across the 2 quarters.   (2) Marketing stimulus start at the same time for all individuals in your treatment group(s)? They do. TG2 members received the  stimulus at the beginning of sales Q1, while  TG1 members did so at the beginning of sales Q2.    (3) Overlap or synergy between the two treatment groups?  Not certain if I understand what you imply by overlap, but the individuals in the 3 groups are mutually exclusive-  no individual who is a member of TG1 is included in TG2 or the CG.

Comment: And is the second treatment group only treated in the first quarter?

Comment: And is the second treatment group only treated in the first quarter? Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with estimating the effects of *both treatments* in one equation is the inclusion of the time dummies separating pre- versus post-treatment. The pre-treatment period for group 1 is, technically, the post-treatment period for group 2.

Let's try to formalize this by writing out your difference-in-differences equation. Here is the canonical specification with two treatment groups.

$$
y_{it} = \alpha + \gamma_1 T^{1}_{i} +  \gamma_2 T^{2}_{i} + \lambda_1 B_{t} + \lambda_2 A_{t} + \delta_1 (T^{1}_{i} \times B_{t}) + \delta_2 (T^{2}_{i} \times A_{t} ) + \epsilon_{it},
$$

- $T^{1}_{i}$ = 1 for individuals in Treatment Group 1, 0 otherwise
- $T^{2}_{i}$ = 1 for individuals in Treatment Group 2, 0 otherwise
- $B_{t}$ = 1 in Quarter 1, 0 otherwise (i.e., "before" period)
- $A_{t}$ = 1 in Quarter 2, 0 otherwise (i.e., "after" period)

The redundancies should be evident. Note how $B_{t}$ and $A_{t}$ index all epochs. One time indicator *must* be dropped to avoid collinearity. If the pre-period is dropped, which will likely be the case if estimated in the order presented above, then software will only return an estimate for $\delta_2$.

In my opinion, I would run two separate equations. The first would only include $T^{1}_{i}$ and your controls; the second would only include $T^{2}_{i}$ and your controls. The latter equation is the effect of *withdrawing* treatment (i.e., switching from 1 to 0). It's rare to observe entities starting out in a treated condition, but the equation is estimable.

Technically, it doesn't matter which epoch we set as a reference. In most cases, the absolute value of the treatment effect is the same either way, they're just opposite in sign. This is true in general. However, symmetry isn't always guaranteed. Say revenue was log-transformed. Here, the effect of moving into treatment (i.e., switching from 0 to 1) isn't the same as moving out (i.e., switching from 1 to 0).

In short, including multiple treatment groups into one model isn't appropriate. The second group of individuals (i.e., $T^{2}_{i}$) don't have any pre-event data. In my opinion, I would subject the customers whose marketing stimulus was removed to a separate analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed argument ! To confirm, your final recommendation would then be, to consider data for TG1 and CG across the 2 quarters to estimate the impact of the stimulus..

Comment: Yes. Your analysis for the first treatment group is valid.

Comment: Thank you Thomas!